# MongoDB cluster time too far from wall clock time

Tags: mongodb

I am maintaining a rocket chat server which relies on a Mongo DB internally.
Recently the linux machine's date was accidentally changed to 2022, and since i changed it back the mongo instance refuses to start, claiming that "New cluster time 1666775701 is too far from this nodes wall clock time 1603715107"

How do I set mongo's clock back to the correct time from the mongo shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### tldr

Start your instance with [maxAcceptableLogicalClockDriftSecs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/parameters/index.html#param.maxAcceptableLogicalClockDriftSecs) large enough to cover the period. From the error message it seems 63060594 should be enough, but be generous, give it e.g. 94608000 (3 years). Backup data after server spins up. If you can afford it, nuke the database and restore it from backup. Restart mongo with normal/default maxAcceptableLogicalClockDriftSecs

#### explanations

Mongo causal consistency model is based on [Lamport logical clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamport_timestamp). It is being used internally in oplog and all replication logic relies on it.

When you accidentally change system date to the future the timestamp advances accordingly. When you roll back system date back to ntp-based time you need to reset the timestamp as well. Default maxAcceptableLogicalClockDriftSecs gives you 1 year which is more than enough for normal operations.

Adjusting this value will let you start mongo and recover it's state. It won't fix any dates from user space - it's totally your responsibility. Mongo knows noting about meaning of your date from your application perspective.

You don't need to start rocket server with custom command line parameters - start mongo manually, [back up data](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongodump/), nuke the db, restore data, stop mongod, start rocket server.

Comment: i tried dumping the database but the bad dates are still kept in the dump, so restoring simply brings back the error. And unfortunately Rocket does not support running mongo with a custom command line.

Comment: How did you manage to "dump" the database without running server?

Comment: I  have added some explanations. If you care about your data but unsure what are you doing, please seek professional help. If you have a recent backup and can afford losing data added after that - restore from the backup.